# Why so many "page not found" for statistics.php?

Tags: 7, nodes

In my Drupal sites, there are many "page not found" for `modules/statistics/statistics.php` recorded in the log ("Recent log messages" or `/admin/reports/dblog`).
Many of them were accessed by the admininistrator in the record.
The file exists, of course.

That seems strange to me.  Why is it so?

Note the core `statistics` module (Ver.7.32) is enabled, and all the three options (access log, Count content views, Use Ajax to increment the counter) in its configuration are enabled.

**[Description added]**
In the Report page `/admin/reports/dblog` when I click the links `modules/statistics/statistics.php` in the Message part, I see (for TYPE: `page not found`) the LOCATION of `http://MyHost/en/modules/statistics/statistics.php` or alike, that is, path with the language prefix.  My websites use the path-prefix-based i18n feature.

Comment: Did you make any changes in the .htaccess (or web server vhost) configuration?

Comment: No change in `.htaccess`.  For the localhost, vhost is setup.  For the other, it is on the shared-hosting server and is not virtual but real.  Both of them show the same error message for admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If file exists, but Drupal still captures calls to it, it may mean one of few things:

1. Obviously this happens if filename is misspelled in one place (request or filesystem) but not the other (or misspelled differently in both).
2. As above, sometimes this happens when paths are (slightly) different.
3. Path you see in your address bar and path your server use to test for file existence are not the same thing. May look the same, but may not, depends on your .htaccess, nginx.conf or whatever you use to control that.
4. Language prefixes may break things. If file `/sites/default/files/example.jpg` exists, server may fail to find `en/sites/default/files/example.jpg`. If that's the case, and for any reason you can't fix broken code, you can try setup like this in your htaccess:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(en|de|fr)/(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %2 -f
   RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/(.*)$ $2 [NC,QSA,L]
   ```

   Notice, I didn't test it. [OP preferred to use](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135751/why-so-many-page-not-found-for-statistics-php/135773#comment163215_135773) *`%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to deal with the potential dependencies on the environment/timing etc* - that are implementation details beyond the scope of this site, I believe. The **logic behind it** is, line by line:

   1. Test if request filename contains one of the specified prefixes (should match your site's languages.
   2. Test if file without prefix (second regex group) is there, and really is a file.
   3. If so, rewrite request to remove language prefix.

   Apply this logic and you should be good. Actual implementation may vary, but logic you want is just that.

Comment: As far as I carefully checked, neither 1 nor 2 is the case.  As for 3, I haven't manually edited .htaccess or nginx.conf or else to control the access, and so Drupal (and the default HTTP server) takes a full control of it.

Comment: 4 is the most suspicious.  See the end of the question, where I have added a description.  That is interesting - `statistics.php` is a core feature.  Does this mean many (or all) Drupal servers that use path-prefix-based language feature experience this?   All the modules used in my sites are I think fairly to extremely popular ones, except for my own, which does nothing at all with the statistics module (at least explicitly, or as far as I am aware).

Comment: @MasaSakano on nginx by default yes. See [this question I asked on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/q/637641/190745) for example. Also, googling "drupal language prefix file links" shows it is a problem in many modules.

Comment: I see, but the server of my sites is Apache.  The suggested keyword for googling is spot on, thank you!  Now I shall create the symlink from `en/modules/statistics/statistics.php` and see what will happen.  Hope nothing will break down or cause knock-on effects…

Comment: @MasaSakano I did my best to translate this to Apache. Haven't tested. See my updated answer

Comment: No, creating the symlink from `en/modules/statistics/statistics.php` does have a knock-on effect.  Access to the frontpage `http://MyDomain/en` will break down (of course…).

Comment: @MasaSakano who told you to create symlink?!

Comment: I have followed your answer.  With some modification (I edited your answer, waiting for approval), it has worked!  The main point in the modification is to use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to deal with the potential dependencies on the environment/timing etc (*cf.* [mod_rewrite reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)).

Comment: This has actually solved the problem I have been encoutering: the page-view counter was not working.  Thank you for your help, and I have put it forward by posting a Q&A: [Why page-view counters not working (displayed)?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135847/why-page-view-counters-not-working-displayed)

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug report for this @ https://www.drupal.org/node/2172871

A temporary fix available @ https://www.drupal.org/node/2172871#comment-10247397

No need to hack the core. Just add the below function in your theme or module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_url_outbound_alter().
 *
 * Fix statistics path when i18n path prefix enabled
 * see: https://www.drupal.org/node/2172871
 */
function YOUR_THEME_OR MODULE_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if ($original_path === 'modules/statistics/statistics.php' && isset($options['prefix'])) {
    $options['prefix'] = '';
  }
}
```